# Shading command produces different results in MATLAB and Octave

Tags: matlab, plot, graphics, gnuplot, octave

The commands  `shading faceted` and `shading interp` produce different figures in MATLAB and Octave.

Consider this code:

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(0:2, 0:2);
Z = magic(3);

figure;
colormap('jet');

subplot(1, 3 ,1);
imagesc(Z);
axis xy
yticklabels({'0', '1', '2'})
yticks(1:3)
xticklabels({'0', '1', '2'})
xticks(1:3)
title('imagesc(Z)');

subplot(1,3,2);
surf(X, Y, Z);
shading faceted;
view([0,0,1]);
yticks(0:3)
xticks(0:3)
title('surf(X, Y, Z); shading faceted;');

subplot(1,3,3);
surf(X, Y, Z);
shading interp;
view([0,0,1]);
yticks(0:3)
xticks(0:3)
title('surf(X, Y, Z); shading interp;');
```

This is the result in MATLAB:
[image]

And the result generated by Octave:

[image]

MATLAB generates a correct figure.What is wrong with this Octave figure?

What is the reason we get two different outputs? Is it an issue with to the `view` command?

### **EDIT (After Bug Report)**

It's been fixed for Ocatve 6.1: https://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/raw-file/11072ea6a16c/scripts/plot/appearance/view.m

Comment: Note that the last 2 plots in octave have the `y` axis inverted. I suspect that makes a big difference. Maybe octave permutes the input somehow too

Comment: In line with @Ander's comment: `view([0, 0, -1])` in Octave seems to produce comparable outputs with respect to the MATLAB version.

Comment: @HansHirse `view([0, 0, -1])` does not produce the same result.

Comment: @sci9 I had a second look, and you're right! Setting no `view` at all reveals that the plot itself is comparable, so the `view` problem might need to be fixed differently... Nevertheless, Ander's comment is still valid.

Comment: Is it that the `y` axis is inverted, or that the `x` and `y` axes are exchanged? Look again at the color arrangement. I threw in an `xlabel('X axis')` call to clarify this, and it looks like in Octave, the X axis is ending up on the vertical axis instead of the horizontal axis.

Comment: I would debate the fact that the matlab version is 'correct'. I get a different result from the above in octave, which seems much more reasonable as an interpolation. Still, yes, something fishy is going on here on both. (tested on Octave 5.1.0. and Matlab R2018b)   EDIT: The octave interpolation https://i.stack.imgur.com/io6lx.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks right. I can reproduce in Octave 4.4 and 5.2 on macOS.

Throw in an `xlabel('X Axis');` call to clarify what's going on.

This sure looks like a bug in Octave's implementation of `view`. It appears the X and Y axes are getting swapped. Could you report this as a bug on the Octave issue tracker at https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=octave?

Comment: And what about the `ylabel('Y axis')`? I see no output for this call on the figure!

Comment: please see bug #57800: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?57800

Comment: It's been fixed for Ocatve 6.1.

Comment: Hooray! Always glad when something gets a timely fix. Thanks for reporting it.